# oracle SQL: selecting distinct value where it does not contain another certain value in all its record

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the current database record that I have, and I only want it to display all the name of students who have never been enrolled in Science.

```
Name        | Subject     | Year
-----------------------------------
Ian Lee     | Math        | 2008
Ian Lee     | Science     | 2008
Ian Lee     | Econs       | 2006
Marie-Ann   | Geography   | 2006
Marie-Ann   | Literature  | 2009
Natalie S.  | Geography   | 2006
Julienne    | Math        | 2008
Julienne    | Science     | 2008
Julienne    | Literature  | 2009
Liam        | Literature  | 2009
Liam        | Econs       | 2006
```

I also have a student record Emily Toh that has not been enrolled in any classes yet. But the correct output should be

```
Name
------------
Marie-Ann
Natalie S.
Emily Toh
Liam
```

This was what I used to call

```
SELECT DISTINCT en.Name
FROM ENROLLMENT en
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT st.Name
    FROM STUDENT st
    WHERE en.Name = st.Name
    AND en.Subject = 'Science'
);
```

But it still gives me a display of all the student names.

The student table and enrollemnt table is as per:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
    Name       VARCHAR2(50),
    DOB        DATE,
    Address    VARCHAR(70),
CONSTRAINT STUDENT_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (Name)
);

CREATE TABLE ENROLLMENT(
    Name       VARCHAR2(50),
    Subject    VARCHAR2(70),
    Year       Number(4),
CONSTRAINT ENROLLMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY (Name, Subject)
CONSTRAINT ENROLLMENT_FKEY FOREIGN KEY (Name) REFERENCES TO STUDENT (Name)
);
```

Comment: post table design of ENROLLMENT and STUDENT

Comment: Swap the table names.

Comment: In addition to the table definitions, please show sample data from both and label each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you made is right, just start with `STUDENTS` table, and look for the science enrollment using `NOT EXISTS`.

```
SELECT  st.Name
FROM STUDENT st
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT st.Name
    FROM enrollment en
    WHERE en.Name = st.Name
    AND en.Subject = 'Science'
);
```

Comment: This one worked for me as how I wanted the output to be, thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a subquery to identify all students which you *don't* want in your result set (i.e. those who were enrolled in Science at some point), and then join to filter off these students.

```
SELECT s.Name      -- , s.Id
FROM STUDENT s
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Name    -- , Id
    FROM ENROLLMENT
    WHERE Subject = 'Science'
) t
    ON s.Name = t.Name   -- AND s.Id = t.Id
WHERE t.Name IS NULL
```

This approach will capture both students who are enrolled in no classes *and* students who enrolled, but never enrolled in Science.

Ideally there should also be an `Id` column associated with each student in both tables.  Without this, joining in a meaningful way could be difficult if two or more students were to share the same name.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to worry about students who have not enrolled in any classes then you can use `GROUP BY ... HAVING ...` like this:

```
SELECT   name
FROM     enrollment
GROUP BY name
HAVING   COUNT( CASE WHEN subject = 'Science' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) = 0;
```

If you have students who have not enrolled for any classes and you want to include them in your output then:

```
SELECT   s.name
FROM     student s
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         enrollment e
         ON ( s.name = e.name AND e.subject = 'Science' )
GROUP BY s.name
HAVING   COUNT( e.subject ) = 0;
```

Since `name` and `subject` are the composite primary key for the table then the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses could be replaced with a `subject IS NULL` check:

```
SELECT   s.name
FROM     student s
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         enrollment e
         ON ( s.name = e.name AND e.subject = 'Science' )
WHERE    e.subject IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hi this one has worked, but the student Emily Toh that is not recorded in the enrollment table could not be displayed.

Comment: @Monomoni Did you try the second query where I stated that exact case?